# Cannot download file with DownloadFileAsync vb.net

Tags: downloadfileasync

I have a url like :

```
Dim processingUrl as String = "http://myIP//myPage.aspx?ID=123321123&ReportType=999"
```

I cannot use DownloadFileAsync to download my processingUrl. I guess it must be specific like:

`http://somesite.com/file.zip`

So how can I download my processingUrl